# Count how many substrings exist in a Fibonacci string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, fibonacci

**The problem is this:**

You are given an integer `N` and a substring `SUB`

The Fibonacci String follows the following rules:

```
F\[0\] = 'A'

F\[1\] = 'B'

F\[k\] = F\[k - 2\] + F\[k - 1\]

(Meaning F\[2\] = 'AB', F\[3\] = 'BAB', F\[4\] = 'ABBAB',...)
```

Task: Count how many times substring `SUB` appears in `F\[n\]`

Sample cases:

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| 4 AB | 2 |
| 6 BAB | 4 |

(N <= 5 * 10^3, 1 <= SUB.length() <= 50)

I had an overall understanding of the problem and wanting to find a more optimal way to solve that problem

My approach is following the fomula `F\[k\] = F\[k - 2\] + F\[k - 1\]` and then run loop tills it reaches (`F\[k\].length - 1`), each loop I extract a substring from `F\[k\]` at i with the same length as `SUB` (call it F_sub), then I check whether `F_sub` equals to SUB or not, if yes I increase count (Yes, this approach is not optimal enough for the big tests)

I am also thinking whether Dynamic Programing is suited for this problem or not

Comment: what is your specific question? Hint: such puzzles aim at finding a trick. The brute force method usually fails. The string follows some pattern and I am certain that if you put some brain on it you can get the result without actually constructing the full fibonacci string

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You cannot brute-force it. `F[30]` has already more than a million letters in it.

Comment: you can store what number of occurences and length of prefixes and postfixes of the string F[n] has. Then you mix-n-match.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with the first 2 strings that are at least as long as **SUB**, you should switch the representation of the strings **F[n]**.  Instead of remembering the complete string, you only need to remember 3 numbers:

1. occurrences: the number of times **SUB** occurs within the string
2. prefix: The length of the longest prefix of the string that is a proper suffix of SUB
3. suffix: The length of the longest suffix of the string that is a proper prefix of SUB

Given **o**, **p**, an **s** for **F[k]** and **F[k+1]**, you can calculate them for the concatenation **F[k+2]**:

- **F[k+2].p** = **F[k].p**
- **F[k+2].s** = **F[k+1].s**
- **F[k+2].o** = **F[k].o** + **F[k+1].o** + **JOIN(F[k].s,F[k+1].p)**

The function **JOIN(a,b)** calculates the number of occurrences of **SUB** within the first **a** characters of **SUB** joined to the last **b** characters of **SUB**.  There are only **|SUB|<sup>2</sup>** values.  In fact, since all the values for **p** and **s** are copied from the first 2 strings, there are only 4 values of this function that will be used. You can calculate them in advance.

**F[N].o** is the answer you are looking for.

A straightforward implementation of this takes **O(N + |SUB|<sup>2</sup>)**, assuming constant time mathematical operations.  Since |SUB| <= 50, this is quite efficient.

If the constraint on N was much larger, there's an optimization using matrix exponentiation that could bring the complexity down to O(log N + |SUB|<sup>2</sup>), but that's not necessary under the given constraints.

Comment: It's not mixed up.  When you join 2 strings, you get the occurrences in the first one, the occurrences in the second one, and new occurrences that span the gap.  Each new occurrence consists of a prefix from the end of the first string, and a suffix from the start of the second.  The longest possible prefix and suffix  are the new string you have to search in.